# Where can I find the proof that the axiom of choice is equivalent to "every set is a projective object in $\bf Set$"?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, axiom-of-choice

I've read it on Wikipedia that in the category of Sets, the statement "*every set is a projective object*" is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice.

I'd like some references with this proof but I'm having trouble finding them. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I don't know a published reference, but I gave a proof at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558623/what-is-a-projective-object-in-rm-set.

Comment: You should pick a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to Andreas Blass,

> Blass, Andreas "**[Injectivity, Projectivity, and the Axiom of Choice.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1979-0542870-6)**" *Transactions of the American Mathematical Society*, Vol. **255**, (Nov., 1979), pp. 31-59

Comment: Well, this result is mentioned in passing on the second page, but is that really the original source of it?  It's a rather trivial result, that I imagine was known from the first moment anyone pondered what projective objects are in general categories.

Comment: Well. That's the reference I know. Maybe Andreas will stop by and clarify. History is full of nearly trivial observations that were only made quite late.

Comment: And there is a lot more to this paper than the "rather trivial result" enquired about here.

Answer (score 3):

Let $E_{\alpha}$ be a collection of nonempty, pairwise disjoint sets, let $\Lambda$ be the index set, let $\cup_{\alpha \in \Lambda} E_{\alpha}$ be denoted by $E$. Consider the diagram with maps $id: \Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda$ and $e: E: \rightarrow \Lambda$ where $e(x)=\alpha \mbox{ if } x \in E_{\alpha}$, note that this function is well defined as the sets $E_{\alpha}$ are pairwise disjoint. Now $\Lambda$ projective implies there is a map $c : \Lambda \rightarrow E$ such that the diagram commutes which is essentially the axiom of choice. And Axiom of choice will imply there is such a map. Thus finishing the proof.

Comment: You probably want your sets to be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Right forgot to put emphasis on that.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.